# How to get all the values of ID in two tables without using set operations

Tags: mysql

Two tables

```
Customer_Fixed_Deposit(
    ID int primary key,
    name varchar(20),
    Fixed_Deposit int
);

Customer_Loan(
    ID int primary key,
    name varchar(20),
    Loan int
);
```

I want the ID of all the customers and with names in both the tables without using set operations

I tried to insert all the values of id and name in 1 table into another, because there were duplicates and ID is the primary key it did not work

Comment: Please share some sample result data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have two tables with two different sets of people and IDs?  If so, then I think a UNION would allow you to select all the IDs and Names from each table into one result.  Try this:

```
SELECT 
    ID, name
FROM 
    Customer_Fixed_Deposit
UNION
SELECT
    ID, name
FROM
    Customer_Loan;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all customers with the same name, assuming names are unique.

```
SELECT fd.id, fd.name, l.id, l.name
FROM Customer_Fixed_Deposit fd
JOIN Customer_Loan l
ON fd.name = l.name;
```

Now, if you want to insert only those customers to `Customer_Loan` table who are not already present in it.

```
INSERT INTO Customer_Loan (name)
SELECT name
FROM Customer_Fixed_Deposit
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT fd.id
    FROM Customer_Fixed_Deposit fd
    JOIN Customer_Loan l
    ON fd.name = l.name;
);
```